# Index organized table for frequent DML

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone explain if index organized table good for frequent DML. 
How it behaves when you insert new row in the index organized table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Oracle: yes, if all your accesses are via the primary key. But as with everything: you won't know until you've tested it for your specific application.

Comment: The main use case for IOTs is reference data lookups, which usually consist of a code (or technical key) and a code description. Reference data is usually slow moving, so it seems unlikely your table with *"frequent DML"* fits the bill. But maybe it does. There's really do little information in your question for anybody to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about performance.

It depends on which DML.

Reading using the primary key index should be very fast. The rest of the operations, no so much.

Remember that IOTs suffer from dual index lookup, since they have no heap. That makes them slower when accessing and filtering data using any index that is not the primary key.

In the end, you would need to measure it. Run some benchmarks and see.

However, you should consider that high performant databases (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) prefer heap structures.